# Reading a key from a file

Tags: java, file, cryptography

I am generating a random key using the following and want to store it to a file. I print out the value.

```
String keyfile = "key.txt";

KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(keylen);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
byte[] encoded = secretKey.getEncoded();
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(keyfile));
IOUtils.write(encoded, output);

System.out.println("Secret key is: " + encoded.toString());
```

I then read it using this:

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(keyfile);
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(f);
System.out.println("Key is: " + data.toString());
```

However the values that are printed do not match. What am I doing wrong?
Shouldn't the values be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toString() of byte[] returns the HashCode and the Hashcode of an Array may be different even if the content is the same as long as the Array is not the same (just equal to).

Answer (score 0):

`byte[].toString()` is not overridden from `Object.toString()` and therefore doesn't depend on the contents of the array. You need `Arrays.toString()`.